# Get specific number of rows from JSON array

Tags: jquery, json

I have `ajax` in my code to get `json` data from a `php` file. My question is, how can I get specific number of rows, starts from a specific index number. I'm using an auto increment value and `if-else` condition to get this result, which is not professional. Is there any `jquery` function to get this?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "demo_test.php", 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
       var x = 0;
       $.each(data, function (i, item) {
           if(x=>desired index && x <= (desired index+rows needed )){
           }
           x++;         
       }); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method to get a swallow copy of array into a new array.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

console.log(
  arr.slice(1, 5)
)
```

---

With your code get array and iterate using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "demo_test.php", 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
       data.slice(1, 5).forEach(function (item, i) { // 1 : start index; 5: end index 

       }); 
    }
});
```